# Angular and RxJS - send email after all values successfully emitted

Tags: angular, rxjs6

saveData$ is an observable that emits multiple values.

I want to send an e-mail once all the values are successfully emitted.

Currently, an email is sent for every value that is emitted.

How do I send the email once, after all of the values are successfully emitted?

```
saveData$.pipe(
  switchMap((value) => {
    return this.service
      .sendEmail(
        this.id
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
          return throwError({
            customErrorType: 'Error sending email on create',
            error,
          });
        })
      );
  })
).subscribe();
```

Comment: If you want to trigger when an observable stream is finished consider using `last` https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last

Answer (score 0):

Use the `last` filtering operator like below with your existing code

```
saveData$.pipe(
  last(),
  switchMap((value) => {
    return this.service
      .sendEmail(
        this.id
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
          return throwError({
            customErrorType: 'Error sending email on create',
            error,
          });
        })
      );
  })
).subscribe();
```